# ver el autocompletado de Visual Studio code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

alguien sabe como hacer para que ver las palabras y no esas líneas que aparecen en la ventana de autocompletado?
gracias soy nuevo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Prueba a darle **F1** y escribe “Preferences“. Selecciona `Preferences: Open settings (JSON)` para que te abra dicho archivo. Una vez dentro añade dentro de las llaves, no fuera:

```
 // Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
 "editor.quickSuggestions": { "other": false, "comments": false, "strings": false },

 // Controls if suggestions should be accepted with "Enter" - in addition to "Tab". Helps to avoid ambiguity between inserting new lines and accepting suggestions.
 "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",

 // Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up.
 "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,

 // Enable word based suggestions
 "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
```

Debería de no aparecer nuevamente, si deseas reactivarlo realiza el mismo paso solo que quitando el código comentado, espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me sigue apareciendo lo mismo. sigo sin poder ver las palabas del autocompletado

Comment: @Roberto_Lo en otros proyectos te hace lo mismo o en ese únicamente?

Comment: Hola, en todos los proyectos.